Parallelisation of fuzzy unsupervised c-means algorithm does not scale
I'm trying to parallelize the fuzzy unsupervised c-means algorithm with OpenMP and I have done it and the problem is when I use 16/32 threads it should give better results than 8/4 threads but the opposite happens and it gets worse and I'm not using threads more than the cores and I know that's due to race conditions but I don't know how to fix it.
Parallelized code is :
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <omp.h>
#include <time.h>

#define MAX_DATA_POINTS 10000
#define MAX_CLUSTER 100
#define MAX_DATA_DIMENSION 5

int num_data_points;
int num_clusters;
int num_dimensions;
double low_high[MAX_DATA_DIMENSION][2];
double degree_of_memb[MAX_DATA_POINTS][MAX_CLUSTER];
double epsilon;
double fuzziness;
double data_point[MAX_DATA_POINTS][MAX_DATA_DIMENSION];
double cluster_centre[MAX_CLUSTER][MAX_DATA_DIMENSION];
double norms[MAX_DATA_POINTS][MAX_CLUSTER]; // Precomputed norms

// Initialize data and membership matrix
int init(char *fname) {
    int i, j, r, rval;
    FILE *f;
    double s;
    if ((f = fopen(fname, "r")) == NULL) {
        printf("Failed to open input file.");
        return -1;
    }
    fscanf(f, "%d %d %d", &num_data_points, &num_clusters, &num_dimensions);
    if (num_clusters > MAX_CLUSTER || num_data_points > MAX_DATA_POINTS || num_dimensions > MAX_DATA_DIMENSION) {
        printf("Input data exceeds defined limits.\n");
        fclose(f);
        exit(1);
    }

    fscanf(f, "%lf %lf", &fuzziness, &epsilon);
    if (fuzziness <= 1.0 || epsilon <= 0.0 || epsilon > 1.0) {
        printf("Invalid fuzziness or epsilon.\n");
        fclose(f);
        exit(1);
    }

    // Initialize data points and their range
    for (i = 0; i < num_dimensions; i++) {
        low_high[i][0] = __DBL_MAX__;
        low_high[i][1] = -__DBL_MAX__;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < num_data_points; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < num_dimensions; j++) {
            fscanf(f, "%lf", &data_point[i][j]);
            if (data_point[i][j] < low_high[j][0])
                low_high[j][0] = data_point[i][j];
            if (data_point[i][j] > low_high[j][1])
                low_high[j][1] = data_point[i][j];
        }
    }

    // Initialize membership matrix randomly
    for (i = 0; i < num_data_points; i++) {
        s = 0.0;
        r = 100;
        for (j = 1; j < num_clusters; j++) {
            rval = rand() % (r + 1);
            r -= rval;
            degree_of_memb[i][j] = rval / 100.0;
            s += degree_of_memb[i][j];
        }
        degree_of_memb[i][0] = 1.0 - s;
    }

    fclose(f);
    return 0;
}

// Precompute norms to avoid redundant calculations
void precompute_norms() {
    #pragma omp parallel for collapse(2)
    for (int i = 0; i < num_data_points; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < num_clusters; j++) {
            double sum = 0.0;
            for (int k = 0; k < num_dimensions; k++) {
                double diff = data_point[i][k] - cluster_centre[j][k];
                sum += diff * diff;
            }
            norms[i][j] = sqrt(sum);
        }
    }
}

// Calculate new cluster centers
int calculate_centre_vectors() {
    double t[MAX_DATA_POINTS][MAX_CLUSTER];

    #pragma omp parallel for collapse(2)
    for (int i = 0; i < num_data_points; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < num_clusters; j++) {
            t[i][j] = pow(degree_of_memb[i][j], fuzziness);
        }
    }

    #pragma omp parallel for collapse(2)
    for (int j = 0; j < num_clusters; j++) {
        for (int k = 0; k < num_dimensions; k++) {
            double numerator = 0.0;
            double denominator = 0.0;
            for (int i = 0; i < num_data_points; i++) {
                numerator += t[i][j] * data_point[i][k];
                denominator += t[i][j];
            }
            cluster_centre[j][k] = numerator / denominator;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

// Update membership values
double update_degree_of_membership() {
    double max_diff = 0.0;

    // Precompute norms
    precompute_norms();

    #pragma omp parallel for reduction(max:max_diff) collapse(2)
    for (int i = 0; i < num_data_points; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < num_clusters; j++) {
            double sum = 0.0;
            double norm_ij = norms[i][j];
            for (int k = 0; k < num_clusters; k++) {
                sum += pow(norm_ij / norms[i][k], 2.0 / (fuzziness - 1));
            }
            double new_uij = 1.0 / sum;
            double diff = fabs(new_uij - degree_of_memb[i][j]);
            if (diff > max_diff) {
                max_diff = diff;
            }
            degree_of_memb[i][j] = new_uij;
        }
    }
    return max_diff;
}

// FCM clustering process
int fcm(char *fname) {
    double max_diff;
    if (init(fname) != 0) return -1;
    do {
        calculate_centre_vectors();
        max_diff = update_degree_of_membership();
    } while (max_diff > epsilon);
    return 0;
}

// Print membership matrix to a file or stdout
void print_membership_matrix(char *fname) {
    int i, j;
    FILE *f;
    if (fname == NULL)
        f = stdout;
    else if ((f = fopen(fname, "w")) == NULL) {
        printf("Cannot create output file.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    fprintf(f, "Membership matrix Parallel:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < num_data_points; i++) {
        fprintf(f, "Data[%d]: ", i);
        for (j = 0; j < num_clusters; j++) {
            fprintf(f, "%lf ", degree_of_memb[i][j]);
        }
        fprintf(f, "\n");
    }
    if (fname != NULL)
        fclose(f);
}

// Main function
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    if (argc != 2) {
        printf("USAGE: fcm <input file>\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    double start_time = omp_get_wtime();
    fcm(argv[1]);
    double end_time = omp_get_wtime();
    double execution_time = end_time - start_time;
    printf("Number of data points: %d\n", num_data_points);
    printf("Number of clusters: %d\n", num_clusters);
    printf("Number of data-point dimensions: %d\n", num_dimensions);
    printf("Accuracy margin: %lf\n", epsilon);
    print_membership_matrix("membership.matrix");
    printf("The program took %f seconds.\n", execution_time);
    return 0;
}

I tried to optimize the performance and it got worse when I increased the number of threads.

Could you provide more information regarding your system such as the cpu model? There simply isn't enough information to know whether or not this should be happening. If you want to calculate theoretical speedup for your problem checkout Amdahls law

Creating threads has an overhead. If the work you're doing with those threads isn't significantly more time consuming than the time taken to create the threads, performance will probably be worse with more threads. Is the performance still worse if you have say num_data_pointsnum_clusters > 1,000,000threadcount?

you include file i/o in your time measurement. ideally, you should only benchmark your parallel kernel execution.
do the threads always share the numa domain? with your small problem size all data might be located at one numa domain and threads will at some point start accessing data across the interconnect

i use a super computer has a distributedmemory system composed of 354 NUMA shared- memory nodes ech node is composed of 2 Intel Xeon Ice Lake 8352Y at 2.2 GHz, with 32 cores per processor (64 cores per node), and 256 GB of RAM per node.

Please add critical information to the question by editing it instead of commenting it below.

collapse can introduce some overhead compared to normal parallel execution, use it with care. If the iteration space of the outer dimension is large enough there is no good reason to increase the complexity of the loop management. I' not sure, but computing pow for random exponents might lead to varying cost depending on the base value, so you might observe a load imbalance. Also, does your while loop abort after 1 iteration? The calculated error might be sensitive to parallel execution, so that you need more iterations with more threads?
